# Errror ERROR 1064 (42000) on MySQL import

Tags: mysql, freebsd

Been trying to import a WordPress database using the command line on a FreeBSD server:

```
uname -a   
FreeBSD host.com 8.3-i386-20120831 FreeBSD 8.3-i386-20120831 #0: Fri Aug 31 10:36:09 UTC 2012     root@domain.com:/usr/obj/i386/usr/src/sys/SERVER8-I386  i386
```

as I had to many time-outs using PHPMyAdmin as it is a large file I guess . Importing using the CLI command

```
mysql -u user_wp -p -h subdomain.mysql.host.com database --default_character_set utf8 < betazone.sql
```

I got

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 38316: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w' at line 1
```

There I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
```

Any ideas how I can get around this error. Earlier dump using WP DB Backup got imported, but it mangled Russian and some special characters and an import with --default utf8 did not work so I tried a PHPMyAdmin dump and then I had this odd error.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is not a dump, or something prepend it.
Let us take a look to `head betazone.sql`

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be HTML in it. Here is as you asked:
head betazone.sql 
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: sub.mysql.domain.com
-- Generation Time: Jan 14, 2013 at 12:56 PM
-- Server version: 5.0.95
-- PHP Version: 5.3.3
Making and trying a new dump now just in case

Comment: New import was of correct size. Other missed data and therefore did not work. All seems to be OK now and encoding is OK as well.